# Can I use itertools.count to add values in a column, resetting at a certain point?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a list of timestamps from a column in a dataframe, that resets after a certain time to zero. So, if the limit was 4, I want the count to add up the values of the column up to position 4, and then reset to zero, and continue adding the values of the column, from position 5, and so forth until it reaches the length of the column. I used `itertools.islice` earlier in the script to create a counter, so I was wondering if I could use a combination of this and `itertools.count` to do something similar? So far, this is my code:

```
cycle_time = list(itertools.islice(itertools.count(0,raw_data['Total Time (s)'][lens]),range(0, block_cycles),lens))
```

Where `raw_data['Total Time (s)']` contains the values I wish to add up, `block_cycles` is the number I want to add up to in the dataframe column before resetting, and `lens` is the length of the column in the dataframe. Ideally, the output from my list would look like this:

```
print(cycle_time)
0
0.24
0.36
0.57
0
0.13
0.32
0.57
```

Which is calculated from this input:

```
print(raw_data['Total Time (s)'])
0
0.24
0.36
0.57
0.7
0.89
1.14
```

Which I would then append to a new column in a dataframe, `interim_data_output['Cycle time (s)']` which details the time elapsed at that point in the 'cycle'. `block_cycles` is the number of iterations in each large 'cycle' This is what I would do with the list:

`interim_data_output['Cycle time (s)'] = cycle_time`

I'm a bit lost here, is this even possible using these methods? I'd like to use itertools for performance reasons. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of what you want to do with expected output? You want to count or sum? You refer to both.

Comment: Edited to provide context, I want to add the values.

Comment: So you need the zeros in the middle? Because in the dataframe I imagine you don't want the zeros when the count resets?

Comment: The cycle starts at 0 seconds, and then when it begins a new cycle, the time is at 0 seconds again, so this is why I would to add the values up to a point and then reset the addition, and begin to add the values beyond together again. So yes, the zeros would be in the middle

Comment: Ah, ok, so the Total Time column will be zero at the cycle start, so the sum is 0.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: I can't follow: based on the description and the first half of the example, you want to get elapsed time from a timestamp, which starts as `0`, so `0, 0.24, 0.36, 0.57` becomes itself. Then the new starting timestamp is supposed to be `0.57`, which becomes the new `0`, and then `0.7` becomes `0.13=0.7-0.57`, which is okay. But then `0.89` does not become `0.32=0.89-0.57`, but it became `0.19=0.89-0.7` like if the base timestamp was reset again, and similarly `1.14` became `0.25=1.14-0.89` (like if another reset happened), instead of `0.57=1.14-0.57`.

Comment: So you suddenly seem resetting the base timestamp every step, instead of every 4th step, what you initially described and also actually did with the first 4 values.

Comment: Yes, my bad you're right, I don't want to reset the base timestamp every step, just every 4th step. I've modified the expected output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the discussion in the comments, here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total Time (s)':[0, 0.24, 0.36, 0.57, 0.7, 0.89, 1.14]})
```

```
   Total Time (s)
0            0.00
1            0.24
2            0.36
3            0.57
4            0.70
5            0.89
6            1.14
```

You can do:

```
block_cycles = 4

# Calculate cycle times.
cycle_times = df['Total Time (s)'].diff().fillna(0).groupby(df.index // block_cycles).cumsum()

# Insert the desired zeros after all cycles.
for idx in range(block_cycles, cycle_times.index.max(), block_cycles):
    cycle_times.loc[idx-0.5] = 0
    
cycle_times = cycle_times.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(cycle_times)
```

Which gives:

```
0    0.00
1    0.24
2    0.36
3    0.57
4    0.00
5    0.13
6    0.32
7    0.57
Name: Total Time (s), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but I realise I've worded the question wrong and I will need to revise. I don't need the time to add up like this, as it's a rolling time clock that I'm working with, but when it reaches a point I need it to reset to zero. I will revise the expected output to help make sense

Comment: @MurrayRoss ok, then the new column will be longer than the original due to the inserted zeros, right? Regarding to your example, shouldn't the second cycle be 0.13, 0.32, 0.57 given that it started at time 0.57?

Comment: Yes, I realise I made a mistake there, I've edited the expected output, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MurrayRoss thanks, see if my edited answer does what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted! Cheers for your help.